# Scrapy Ignoring Response 303 - HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, http-status-code-303

I want to Scrape Comments from https://m.youtube.com

When I tried to scrape https://m.youtube.com, first its Redirecting me to https://www.youtube.com. I've programmed my spider to not obey the robot.txt, disabled cookies, tried meta=dont_redirect. Now its not redirecting me to https://www.youtube.com but now i get response "Ignoring response <303 https://m.youtube.com/view_comment?v=xHkL9PU7o9k&gl=US&hl=en&client=mv-google>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed" How Can I solve this.

My Spider Code is below:

```
    import scrapy

    class CommentsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'comments'
        allowed_domains = ['m.youtube.com']
        start_urls = [
        'https://m.youtube.com/view_comment? 
        v=xHkL9PU7o9k&gl=US&hl=en&client=mvgoogle'
        ]


def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta = {'dont_redirect': True})

def parse(self, response):
    x = response.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    y = 
       response.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/text()').extract()

    yield{'Comments': (x, y)}
```

'''

Output:

```
2019-07-18 16:07:23 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-07-18 16:07:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (303) <GET https://m.youtube.com/view_comment?v=xHkL9PU7o9k&gl=US&hl=en&client=mv-google> (referer: None)
2019-07-18 16:07:24 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <303 https://m.youtube.com/view_comment?v=xHkL9PU7o9k&gl=US&hl=en&client=mv-google>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2019-07-18 16:07:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 2):

[According to Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror) you can use the `handle_httpstatus_list` spider attribute.

In your case:

```
class CommentsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'comments'
    allowed_domains = ['m.youtube.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://m.youtube.com/view_commentv=xHkL9PU7o9k&gl=US&hl=en&client=mvgoogle'
    ]
    handle_httpstatus_list = [303]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but my problem not solve yet now i get this response "Connection was refused by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.."

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use a user-agent string of a mobile browser to avoid getting redirected:

```
USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1'
headers = {'User-Agent': USER_AGENT}

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=self.headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but my problem not solve yet now i get this response          "Connection was refused by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.."

Comment: Did you try to add handle_httpstatus_list = [303] as Sewake suggested below?

Comment: Works fine for me, maybe they're blocking your IP now. Have you tried using proxies?

Comment: Yes I try using proxies but now I am not getting any result